# How to use Aramex API in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, aramex

I am working on eCommerce project in which I've to use aramex api's for shipping and for other stuff.

I am making project in react native so I don't have any idea how to implement aramex api's in react native?

Please let me know if someone knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an npm package called [aramex-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aramex-api). it should be a good start